# Limit data by user data or role properties

Tags: geoserver

I have a map of points in Belgium. Each point is linked to a specific user. The points are saved into a database. So I created a layer that loaded in all the points.

I want to create a map for each user that only contists of his own data. Is there a possibility to link data to a user, filter the points and generate the map? For security reason, I can't set the user data in the url. So can I create a map for each user without creating for each user a different layer, with a different sql view?

Comment: I'm wondering that geoserver doesn't have this feature out of the box. Or does this changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in the past by creating a custom GeoTools DataStore wrapping a PostGIS one, which would add filters on the fly based on the user, and alter the insert/update/delete statements accordingly (for a customer project, it's not available to the public).

If I were to do it again today I'd probably try to implement a custom ResourceAccessManager using the current user to add a read filter: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/main/src/main/java/org/geoserver/security/ResourceAccessManager.java

Extending GeoFence could also be interesting, there is the ability to set read and write filters already, but not to make them parametric based on the current user name.

As a last alternative, you could setup your own server side proxy that given the user, sets the right viewparam in the requests (assuming they are read only, no WFS-T) and pass that down in a parametric sql view.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to create a view for each user where you only pull out their data (assuming you are tracking this)

`CREATE VIEW <viewName> AS SELECT * FROM <TABLE> WHERE <CreatedBy> = 'UserName'`

Then set permissions on each of the views.